# Эффект затемнения активности

Tags: android, android-material

Возможно ли сделать, чтобы при открытии AlertDialog или PopupWindow фоновое активити затемнялось или был какой-то эффект типа уменьшения прозрачности!?

Как можно это реализовать такое ?? Какими средствами ?

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с api 14 управлять затемнением позади диалога можно так:

```
dialog.getWindow().setDimAmount(0.5f);
```